# Can a MediaWiki site running on Apache Tomcat be transferred to SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, mediawiki

I have a requirement to transfer an internal media wiki site which is running on Cent OS server, Apache tomcat webserver to Sharepoint 2013.

Is it possible to migrate if yes how to proceed with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the answer is no, unless your MediaWiki system contains only trivially basic articles.

MediaWiki and SharePoint are completely different products. They are not compatible in any special way. [MediaWiki](https://mediawiki.org/) is a wiki with hundreds of features and behaviors that do not exist in SharePoint, not even in SharePoint's wiki product. Examples are:

- [Transclusion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Transclusion)
- A thousand [configuration variables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings)
- Many [extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extensions) (plugins) that affect the content

Now, if your wiki content is completely trivial and you don't care about any of MediaWiki's rich features, you can dump all your articles to HTML files (say, using [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or similar) and try to import them into SharePoint somehow. You'll still need to handle embedded images (anything in the `File:` namespace) specially, however. Your HTML files will contain links to the images, and you'll need to change those links to point to the images' new location in SharePoint.

Alternatively, if you're running SharePoint in house (i.e., not as SaaS) on a Windows server, you could install MediaWiki on that server and pretend it's part of SharePoint. :-)

On hearing your question, I can't help but wonder what you're trying to accomplish. Does somebody in your organization just not like MediaWiki (or Linux)? Maybe they don't understand MediaWiki. (That's likely, if they think it can be migrated into SharePoint.) Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Thanks Dan, It's a project transfer scenario, I just had one more thing, is it possible to create a transfer package from MediaWiki and deploy it to a machine with same Database Server and Apache Tomcat... or we can only do transfer from MediaWiki to Mediawiki?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question, but here are some basics. A MediaWiki system has three parts: MediaWiki software (a collection of PHP files), a database, and a webserver configuration (such as Apache conf files). If you want to transfer a MediaWiki system from one host to another, you install the MediaWiki software, copy the database, and create a webserver configuration that points at the PHP files. For copying the database, you have 2 choices -- you can do a full backup and restore (recommended), or you can export the old system's data to XML and import it into the new system.